# Проблема с Laravel Steam Auth

Tags: php, laravel, api, steam-web-api

следующая проблема:
Использую данный пакет: https://github.com/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Invisnik\LaravelSteamAuth\SteamAuth;
use App\User;
use Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * The SteamAuth instance.
     *
     * @var SteamAuth
     */
    protected $steam;

    /**
     * The redirect URL.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectURL = '/profile';

    /**
     * AuthController constructor.
     *
     * @param SteamAuth $steam
     */
    public function __construct(SteamAuth $steam)
    {
        $this->steam = $steam;
    }

    /**
     * Redirect the user to the authentication page
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function redirectToSteam()
    {
        return $this->steam->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Get user info and log in
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */

    public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->steam->validate()) {
            $info = $this->steam->getUserInfo();

            if (!is_null($info)) {
                $user = $this->findOrNewUser($info);

                Auth::login($user, true);

                return redirect($this->redirectURL); // redirect to site
            }
        }
        return $this->redirectToSteam();
    }

    /**
     * Getting user by info or created if not exists
     *
     * @param $info
     * @return User
     */
    protected function findOrNewUser($info)
    {
        $user = User::where('steamid', $info->steamID64)->first();

        if (!is_null($user)) {
//            if ($user->name != $info->personname) { $user->name = $info->personname; $user->save(); } // update info
//            if ($user->avatar != $info->avatarfull) { $user->avatar = $info->avatarfull; $user->save(); }

            return $user;
        }

//        $utm = '';
//        if (Session::has('utm'))
//            $utm = Session::get('utm');

        return User::create([
            'name' => $info->personaname,
            'avatar' => $info->avatarfull,
            'steamid' => $info->steamID64,
            'remember_token' => \Illuminate\Support\Str::random(16),
            //'refer' => $utm
        ]);
    }
}
```

Выше код контроллера.
Работал еще неделю назад на хостинге и на локалке нормально.
После ряда изменений (не связанных со стим) перестало работать на хостинге, на локалке полет отличный, на хостинге получаем следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ума не приложу в чем может быть проблема, многих коллег опросил все разводят руками, может кто то сталкивался с подобным ?

upd. Забыл добавить, ключ менял несколько раз.
Еще при указании левого ключа, на локалке я получаю ошибку - неверный ключ, а тут могу от балды задать и все равно такая ошибка.
Менял домен и хостинг (создавал новый аккаунт у того же хостинг провайдера), но сомневаюсь что проблема в нем

Comment: https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication/issues/135 проверьте с сервера если вы можете достучаться до steam community.com и попробуйте с него скачать ваш адрес. Есть вероятность вы получите редирект, либо что-то ещё вроде бана серверного адреса.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov пробовал. Скрипт оттуда на проверку online/offline выдает два оффлайна, то есть ошибка еще на стадии подключения. Как проверить на бан ? Просил знакомого поставить себе на сервер, тот же хостинг провайдер, те же файлы, только ключ другой, у него все работало отлично. У меня с любым ключом такая фигня. IP бан ?

Comment: Если другой ключ, то вероятно что его и забанили, а не IP. В любом случае лучше написать в [техподдержку Steam](https://support.steampowered.com/newticket.php)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov но загвоздка в том что я не могу использовать и чужой ключ. При этом, используя другой пакет не invisnik я получаю другие ошибки, связанные с опенайди, а тут до опенайди не достучаться вообще, я могу любой ключ вбить и будет 403 forbidden. При этом раньше все работало, и сайт не в продакшене, за что бан, там два человека его смотрело. Саппорт стима помогать отказался, говорят они по апи ничем помочь не могут, там у них только вики 2001 года, и больше ничего :(